# Plot GPX on topographic map with no labels

Tags: gpx, topography

I am trying to plot a path from a GPX file on a topographic map with as few labels as possible. I've played around with a handful of both online and desktop solutions, but it seems that I either don't have enough control over what labels do and don't show up on a given map, or the labels are native to the tiles themselves. The final product of this will be a map that I'll print on letter-sized paper so that we can show it to people as part of a research project. We're willing to spend some money for a piece of software if it will solve this for us in a relatively easy manner. Is there a tool, online or otherwise, that will allow us to do this?

Comment: What solutions have you 'played around' with? Where is your topographic map coming from? is it yours or an online resource?

Comment: I tried gpsvisualizer.com but couldn't get the look I wanted for the map. I tried snazzy maps and found some help with getting the map I wanted but wasn't sure where to go from there in plotting the gpx. I've tried Global Mapper and Expert GPS but found them both lacking for my needs. The map would need to come from online as I don't have my own store of topo maps sitting around.